# new Promise with set state receives an arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, arrow-functions, resolve

I was going through a react code base where I see the Promise function calling setstate with 2 arguments, I cannot exactly decipher how exactly this is working, everywhere I have seen a setState being created having one object argumemnt, but here we have a resolve argument that gets a setstate with an object and an arrow function which is calling resolve. The other arrow function, which I don't have any idea what it's doing and how this code is working

this is what I have for state

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            articles:[],
            loading:true,
            page:1,
            totalResults : 0
        }
    }
```

This is the code that I have in my codebase which I have trouble understanding.

```
handleNextClick = async ()=>{
    await new Promise(resolve => this.setState({page: this.state.page+1}, () => resolve())); // same as await this.setState({page: this.state.page+1});
    await this.updateNews();
}
```

As you can see Promise is receiving theresolve arrow function which is calling setstate with an object and an arrow function. Can someone please explain how this is working exactly.

Comment: since we need to wait until the state has been updated, so await is used for that, lly, for update as well

Comment: The callback runs _after_ the state has been updated so you don't need to await anything.

Comment: in my case, page number was being updated later and we were calling the setState with the stale page variable

Comment: @Andy what's the second arrow function argument that set state is receiving and when does it gets called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't make a lot sense which is probably why it's difficult to understand.

[`setState` has a callback option](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). So you don't need a promise, and you don't need to await the setState either. Further, you probably don't need to await `updateNews` either so you can remove the async from the `handleNextClick` function.

This is likely what the function should look like.

```
handleNextClick () {

  // Set the new state, then use the callback option
  // to call `updateNews`
  this.setState( { page: this.state.page + 1 }, () => {
    this.updateNews();
  });
}
```